# How to create virtual paths to files on web server?

Tags: apache, path

I have two files:  file1.php and file2.php in a directory that contains more files. 
I want to change the path of these two files to be newdir/fileX.php .
I would like to do it without actually changing their physical position, because of images and stuff that appear on these pages.
Running Apache on Linux

Can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using symbolic links. In the terminal go to the newdir directory and type:

```
ln -s path/to/phpfiles/file1.php
```

Comment: In your httpd.conf file, you might want to check you have the following: 
    `<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>`

If not, add it and restart apache.